# How to access my office postgresql server from home?

Tags: networking, postgresql

I have postgresql server on my office system (ubuntu 16.04). and I want to access this postgres database from my home(different network). I don't want to host my postgresql server on cloud. Is it Possible? If there is a way help me out.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Comment: Itis possible, but we need some more information. How are you able to access your office system from home? Does your system have a public IP address or is it behind a router/firewall with NAT? Do you have ssh access (maybe with port forwarding), are you free to access any port on your system from remote? Can you have your network administrator follow your wishes?

Comment: Yes, my office system has a public IP address.  I can get all privileges to access my office server from administrator.

Comment: If there's an administrator you should probably contact them about a suitable server configuration. Then you just need to point the client at the right host name and port.

Comment: First, make sure from the postgresql.conf file, `listen_addresses` is set to the IP address of the interface you want to connect to (or '*' or '0.0.0.0' or '::', depending on your network configuration). See [connection settings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) in the documentation. Then edit pg_hba.conf to meet your needs (see [client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html)). It is not possible to write a complete tutorial here, but there are lots of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 2 ways:

- If the database is exposed on the public ip. Just connect using psql client to that host address.
- Or if access is not that open and you have ssh access. just tunnel up the postgress port on your system using ssh and access it using psql client

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)